# Can I send a status message from an external (standalone) PHP script to the Craft engine?

Tags: php

*Note: this question pertains to Craft 2 Pro. Craft 3 is not currently an option.*

### What I need to do

I have some stand-alone utilities that don't need to exist within the Craft framework, so I would really rather not have to go down the road of learning how to develop Craft extensions.

The trick is that these stand-alone utilities do their thing, and then redirect the user to various Craft entries, and I need some way to send arbitrary status messages from the standalone utilities that can then be displayed by the Craft templates.

### Example Scenario

We are using a external utility for online fundraising. The user starts on a page that exists as a Craft entry ('Donate'), proceeds to the external utility's web space, and is sent back to the Craft site.

If something goes wrong in the transaction, I need to be able to display any number of error messages to the user, *on the original Craft entry*, allowing the user to try the donation again. I don't want to create multiple copies of the original Craft entry, one for each possible error message. That seems like an unreasonable duplication of effort and data, and a nightmare in the making if any changes need to be made to what the user sees.

### What I hoped would be possible

The external utilities exist on the same domain, so I hoped I might be able to use PHP's `$_SESSION` variable to set the status message, and then have the Twig template display the message.

Based on what I found, it seems that Twig (at least in Craft 2) doesn't have access to `$_SESSION` without editing the Craft application code to create a new global variable corresponding to `$_SESSION`. I want to avoid editing Craft application code to ensure that nothing gets clobbered by updates to Craft.

### What to do?

How can I send arbitrary external messages to a Craft entry so that they can be displayed by the Twig template? I don't think I know Craft well enough to know all the possibilities, and so I am not even sure how to search well for what other people have done.

I hope that writing my own extension isn't the answer to this because I haven't figured out how to do that, yet!

### Update!

I went ahead with what was recommended in the "accepted answer" below, and it has worked. Here are the steps that I took:

1. Add a custom route in `config/routes.php` that looks like this:
   `'(?:[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/=]+\/)+error/(\d+)' => '_entry',`
   This matches any URI that ends with `/error/` and a number, and will capture the number as a variable. For an explanation of the regex, [here it is on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/vRCB7a/1).
   **Note:** The version on regex101.com needs one of the forward slashes escaped, but that slash in `config/routes.php` should *not* be escaped.
2. Create a macro that will look up and return the correct error message by using a `switch` statement on the error number, which will be captured in the `matches` variable. The macro looks like this:

```
{% macro show_error(error_id) %}
  {% switch error_id %}
    {% case 10072 %} Error: bad transaction, please try again
    {% default %} Error: error message not found
  {% endswitch %}
{% endmacro %}
```

3. Add code at the beginning of `_entry` to detect if the `matches` variable exists, and then:

   - look up what entry *would have been* loaded by the CraftCMS engine, if this weren't a custom route: `{% set entry = craft.entries.uri(matches[0]).first() %}`
   - save the error message to a variable, using the previously defined macro: `{% set error_message = show_error(matches[1]) %}`
4. Display the error message at the appropriate place in the template:

```
{% if error_message is defined and error_message|length %}
  <div class="error">{{ error_message }}</div>
{% endif %}`
```

5. **Result:** I can append `/error/123` to any entry's URI, and the `_entry` template will be able to integrate the externally-chosen error message in an internal template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to do this would be to add another segment to your URI.
i.e /bla/bla/bla/message-1
Then in your template, read the segment and display the appropriate message.
You could do it all in the template with a switch or conditional or the segment could be the entry slug for the message and you can pull from Craft entries.

Comment: I can work with that! It's not quite "arbitrary message" but I could use a macro in the base layout template, and just add any error messages I ever need to the "errors" macro. And it's probably more advisable to do it that way, anyway, rather than allowing *arbitrary* input, no matter how much I trust my own programming. ;)